# Error when installing cmake for python windows

Tags: python, cmake, pip

I have windows 10 and fresh Python 3.6.1.
I was trying to install package Cmake 0.6.0 (needed for another package, atari-py) using

```
pip install cmake
```

but I'm getting an error.

I have these packages installed: pip,scikit-build, setuptools, wheel, pybdist.
I do have a foreign symbol in my account name (lesson learnt), but it works fine when installing other packages. I am not a skilled windows administrator.

```
Collecting cmake
  Using cached cmake-0.6.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: cmake
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cmake: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cmake: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Čejkis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging1\\cmake\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\EJKIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3br7eri7pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 405, in setup
      cmkr = cmaker.CMaker()
    File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 67, in __init__
      "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build.")

  Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build.

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for cmake
Failed to build cmake
Installing collected packages: cmake
  Running setup.py install for cmake: started
    Running setup.py install for cmake: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Čejkis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging1\\cmake\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\EJKIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5ql_x35g-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 405, in setup
        cmkr = cmaker.CMaker()
      File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 67, in __init__
        "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build.")

    Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build.

    ----------------------------------------

  Failed building wheel for cmake
Command "C:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Čejkis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging1\\cmake\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\EJKIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5ql_x35g-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Čejkis\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging1\cmake\
```

Answer (score 6):

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

and then you can run

`pip3 install cmake`

This works for me on Pyhton 3.8

Answer (score 6):

if the above answers of pip3 or pip install cmake don't work try

sudo apt-get install cmake

Answer (score 1):

As of today, CMake wheels for python 3.6 are available and `pip install cmake` is expected to work.

#### Background

At the time of your first post, there were no wheels for python 3.6, `pip` was rightfully trying to build the wheel using the source distribution.

Considering that:

- the project allowing to generate a CMake wheel itself depends on `scikit-build` and `cmake`
- we simply repackage the existing binaries into the windows wheels

... you got the general error message `Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build`.

References:

- http://cmake-python-distributions.readthedocs.io
- http://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/

#### Installing atari-py on windows

Looking at the documentation and open pull requests of the corresponding project, it look like windows is not supported. See https://github.com/openai/atari-py

If you would like to help the project and improve their windows support, let me know and I could try to give you some guidance to create a pull request and simplify their build system.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I installed cmake 0.8 from a binary file from their webpage.
I originally wanted to install package atari-py that needed cmake. I downloaded that from git and in cmd with administrator rights I ran

```
python install setup.py
```

which worked.

```
python setup.py install
```

still didn't work. Unfortunately I can't give any further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded [VS Code](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) with C++ libraries and that did the trick, I was able to install CMake. (I was on Windows 10 btw)