# ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, docker, opencv, cmake, nvidia-jetson-nano

I was trying to install OpenCV4 in a docker on jetson nano. It has jetpack 4.4 s os. The docker was successfully created and Tensorflow is running but while installing OpenCV using pip it is showing CMake error.

```
root@5abf405fb92d:~# pip3 install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading opencv-python-4.4.0.42.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 88.9 MB 2.5 kB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from opencv-python) (1.18.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpqpzwrofy
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-93nxibky/opencv-python
  Complete output (9 lines):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o_hualnr/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 560, in setup
      cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o_hualnr/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 95, in __init__
      self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o_hualnr/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 82, in get_cmake_version
      "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is %s" % cmake_executable)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  
  Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452203/error-when-installing-cmake-for-python-windows

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I had the same problem and i did this,

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

then install opencv again,

```
pip install opencv-python
```

this worked for me

Comment: this answer, should be placed above. at the top! Solves the problem instantly on Windows.

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError

Comment: This error continues to popup on Mac Sierra even after following this.

Comment: Just thought id mention that the pip upgrade command did not work for me and uninstalled pip because I did not add the ``--user`` argument. My venv did not have pip anymore. I then brought pip back via ``python -m ensurepip``. And then running the command again with python -m worked flawlessly: ``python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel``

Comment: It doesn't work for me (Win 11, Python 3.6). However, pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64 worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

If after

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

you still have the same error,

You can try to specify the older version of OpenCV to install.

Ex.

```
pip3 install opencv-python==3.4.13.47
```

Comment: I can verify this. With Python 3.6: pip install opencv-python tried to install 4.7.0.68 but failed in the manner indicated above even after upgrading pip, setuptools and wheel. However, pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64 worked. Exactly as indicated in this answer. It works right out of the box for Python >= 3.7 but I need to use 3.6 and opencv still supports it.

Comment: I too can verify that this works.

Comment: Yep, pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64 worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes .. Finally found a work around.
Follow this https://github.com/mdegans/nano_build_opencv and build from source and finally gets installed.

PS: It may take a bit long for building, for me it took 10 Hrs :P.

Happy Image-Processing..

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing. I am hitting the same error, the numpy with parameter --platform linux/arm/v7 on last night build which took 11 hours and it was still not finished.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and what solved it for me was not to use `python:3-alpine` but `python:3.8-slim`. E.g.:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install build-essential libwrap0-dev libssl-dev libc-ares-dev uuid-dev xsltproc
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes \
        build-essential \
        gcc \
        python3-dev \
        mosquitto \
        mosquitto-clients


RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir \
      numpy scipy matplotlib scikit-build opencv-contrib-python-headless \
      influxdb paho-mqtt configparser Pillow \
      qrcode
```

worked finally for me.

Answer (score 1):

I came across similiar situation
I had error

> Failed to build opencv-python ERROR: Could not build wheels for
> opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
> WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 22.0.4 is
> available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip
> install --upgrade pip' command.

I ran in command prompt with admin privileges following
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Now "pip install opencv-python" works

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in installing OpenCV in Anaconda 3 using Python version 3.6.PIP was not able to build the wheel.

The following two commands solved my issue:

`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

`pip3 install opencv-python==4.7.0.68`

Thanks

Comment: This is @willSapgreen's answer with a different version number for `opencv-python`

Answer (score 0):

please check your python specifications:

```
  - opencv -> python[
version='
>=2.7,<2.8.0a0
>=3.5,<3.6.0a0
>=3.6,<3.7.0a0
>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled it by reinstalling python3 from scratch in my MacBook:

```
brew reinstall python@3.9
```

I also reinstalled numpy and matplotlib packages experimentally.

```
pip3 install numpy
pip3 install matplotlib 
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

The versions:

macOS Mojave 10.14.5
Python 3.9.7
OpenCV 4.5.3

OpenCV's version is 4.5.3 [by this way](https://kirr.co/uux6ty):

```
import cv2 
print(cv2.__version__)
```

But by "[pip list](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-basic/)", it shows "opencv-contrib-python 3.4.9.31".

Answer (score 0):

try using this `pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56`

Comment: Unless there's a reason this *specific* python version should be used, I don't see this value of keeping this answer when this other one exists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855136/

Answer (score 0):

consider installing python3-dev or python3-devel using yum it worked for me with opencv-python-headless when it cant build wheel

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to install opencv in your raspberrypi 3B, Use following steps:

1. sudo raspi-config
2. advanced -- expand filesystem
3. reboot your pi

Open your raspi terminal and do following stuff:

4. use command: sudo apt-get update
5. use command: sudo apt-get upgrade
6. check your python version and upgarde it to latest one
7. install pip and upgrade pip
8. use command: mkdir project
9. use command: cd project
10. create virtual environment
11. activate virtual environment
12. install dependencies ,can get dependencies from https://singleboardbytes.com/647/install-opencv-raspberry-pi-4.htm
13. if error in installing libdhf5-dev
14. use command: sudo apt-get install python3-h5py and reinstall libdhf5-dev
15. use command: pip install scikit-build
16. use command: pip install cython
17. before installing opencv ,make sure you are in virtual environment or
    activate environment
18. use command: pip install --no-cache-dir opencv-contrib-python==4.5.3.56
19. Remember to use mentioned version...

Thank You...

Comment: Please reformat your answer. It looks so bad to read.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31555641)