# Installing opencv2 in Docker for Raspberry Pi (new OS image Bullseye)

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, opencv

I'm trying to install an opencv2 for Docker container in my Raspberry Pi with the newest OS image.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY req.txt req.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
RUN pip3 install -r req.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

requirements contains

```
opencv-python-headless==4.5.4.58
```

And I'm getting this error:

```sh
Setting up libxvidcore4:armhf (2:1.3.7-1) ...
Setting up libx264-160:armhf (2:0.160.3011+gitcde9a93-2.1) ...
Setting up libxxf86vm1:armhf (1:1.1.4-1+b2) ...
Setting up libsnappy1v5:armhf (1.1.8-1) ...
Setting up libflac8:armhf (1.3.3-2) ...
Setting up libxcb-present0:armhf (1.14-3) ...
Setting up libasound2-data (1.2.4-1.1) ...
Setting up libz3-4:armhf (4.8.10-1) ...
Setting up libblas3:armhf (3.9.0-3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/blas/libblas.so.3 to provide /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libblas.so.3 (libblas.so.3-arm-linux-gnueabihf) in auto mode
Setting up libllvm11:armhf (1:11.0.1-2) ...
Setting up libass9:armhf (1:0.15.0-2) ...
Setting up libslang2:armhf (2.3.2-5) ...
Setting up libva2:armhf (2.10.0-1) ...
Setting up libwrap0:armhf (7.6.q-31) ...
Setting up libxfixes3:armhf (1:5.0.3-2) ...
Setting up libxcb-sync1:armhf (1.14-3) ...
Setting up libcodec2-0.9:armhf (0.9.2-4) ...
Setting up libdbus-1-3:armhf (1.12.20-2) ...
Setting up dbus (1.12.20-2) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up libopus0:armhf (1.3.1-0.1) ...
Setting up libxinerama1:armhf (2:1.1.4-2) ...
Setting up libxv1:armhf (2:1.0.11-1) ...
Setting up libvorbis0a:armhf (1.3.7-1) ...
Setting up libxrandr2:armhf (2:1.5.1-1) ...
Setting up libsensors5:armhf (1:3.6.0-7) ...
Setting up libaacs0:armhf (0.9.0-2) ...
Setting up pocketsphinx-en-us (0.8+5prealpha+1-13) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:armhf (20.3.5-1) ...
Setting up libgfortran5:armhf (10.2.1-6) ...
Setting up libvulkan1:armhf (1.2.162.0-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-dri2-0:armhf (1.14-3) ...
Setting up libbdplus0:armhf (0.1.2-3) ...
Setting up libvidstab1.1:armhf (1.1.0-2+b1) ...
Setting up alsa-topology-conf (1.2.4-1) ...
Setting up ocl-icd-libopencl1:armhf (2.2.14-2) ...
Setting up libasyncns0:armhf (0.8-6+b2) ...
Setting up libxshmfence1:armhf (1.3-1) ...
Setting up libvpx6:armhf (1.9.0-1) ...
Setting up libvdpau1:armhf (1.4-3) ...
Setting up libwavpack1:armhf (5.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libbs2b0:armhf (3.1.0+dfsg-2.2+b1) ...
Setting up libxcb-randr0:armhf (1.14-3) ...
Setting up libtheora0:armhf (1.1.1+dfsg.1-15) ...
Setting up libasound2:armhf (1.2.4-1.1) ...
Setting up libopenal-data (1:1.19.1-2) ...
Setting up libwayland-egl1:armhf (1.18.0-2~exp1.1) ...
Setting up libusb-1.0-0:armhf (2:1.0.24-3) ...
Setting up libbluray2:armhf (1:1.2.1-4+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libsamplerate0:armhf (0.2.1+ds0-1) ...
Setting up libdrm-common (2.4.104-1) ...
Setting up libzvbi-common (0.2.35-18) ...
Setting up libmp3lame0:armhf (3.100-3) ...
Setting up libvorbisenc2:armhf (1.3.7-1) ...
Setting up libiec61883-0:armhf (1.2.0-4) ...
Setting up libserd-0-0:armhf (0.30.10-2) ...
Setting up libxkbcommon0:armhf (1.0.3-2) ...
Setting up libwayland-client0:armhf (1.18.0-2~exp1.1) ...
Setting up libavc1394-0:armhf (0.5.4-5) ...
Setting up libzvbi0:armhf (0.2.35-18) ...
Setting up liblapack3:armhf (3.9.0-3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lapack/liblapack.so.3 to provide /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblapack.so.3 (liblapack.so.3-arm-linux-gnueabihf) in auto mode
Setting up libzmq5:armhf (4.3.4-1) ...
Setting up libcaca0:armhf (0.99.beta19-2.2) ...
Setting up alsa-ucm-conf (1.2.4-2) ...
Setting up libcdio-cdda2:armhf (10.2+2.0.0-1+b2) ...
Setting up libcdio-paranoia2:armhf (10.2+2.0.0-1+b2) ...
Setting up libxcursor1:armhf (1:1.2.0-2) ...
Setting up libvorbisfile3:armhf (1.3.7-1) ...
Setting up libdc1394-25:armhf (2.2.6-3) ...
Setting up librubberband2:armhf (1.9.0-1) ...
Setting up libsndio7.0:armhf (1.5.0-3) ...
Setting up libjack-jackd2-0:armhf (1.9.17~dfsg-1) ...
Setting up libdrm2:armhf (2.4.104-1) ...
Setting up libflite1:armhf (2.2-2) ...
Setting up libva-drm2:armhf (2.10.0-1) ...
Setting up libsord-0-0:armhf (0.16.8-2) ...
Setting up libwayland-cursor0:armhf (1.18.0-2~exp1.1) ...
Setting up libsratom-0-0:armhf (0.6.8-1) ...
Setting up libsndfile1:armhf (1.0.31-2) ...
Setting up libva-x11-2:armhf (2.10.0-1) ...
Setting up liblilv-0-0:armhf (0.24.12-2) ...
Setting up libopenmpt0:armhf (0.4.11-1) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu1:armhf (2.4.104-1) ...
Setting up mesa-vulkan-drivers:armhf (20.3.5-1) ...
Setting up libdrm-nouveau2:armhf (2.4.104-1) ...
Setting up libgbm1:armhf (20.3.5-1) ...
Setting up libpulse0:armhf (14.2-2) ...
Setting up libdrm-radeon1:armhf (2.4.104-1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:armhf (20.3.5-1) ...
Setting up libopenal1:armhf (1:1.19.1-2) ...
Setting up libavutil56:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libpostproc55:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libswscale5:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up mesa-va-drivers:armhf (20.3.5-1) ...
Setting up libsdl2-2.0-0:armhf (2.0.14+dfsg2-3) ...
Setting up mesa-vdpau-drivers:armhf (20.3.5-1) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:armhf (20.3.5-1) ...
Setting up libglx0:armhf (1.3.2-1) ...
Setting up libsphinxbase3:armhf (0.8+5prealpha+1-12) ...
Setting up libswresample3:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libavresample4:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libpocketsphinx3:armhf (0.8+5prealpha+1-13) ...
Setting up libgl1:armhf (1.3.2-1) ...
Setting up va-driver-all:armhf (2.10.0-1) ...
Setting up libavcodec58:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libvdpau-va-gl1:armhf (0.4.2-1+b1) ...
Setting up libchromaprint1:armhf (1.5.0-2) ...
Setting up libavformat58:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up vdpau-driver-all:armhf (1.4-3) ...
Setting up libavfilter7:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libavdevice58:armhf (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up ffmpeg (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
Removing intermediate container 1ba73a14a49a
 ---> 0542e1937cad
Step 6/8 : RUN pip3 install -r req.txt
 ---> Running in c2bc64e20849
Collecting certifi==2021.10.8
  Downloading certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.7
  Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting click==8.0.3
  Downloading click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting Flask==2.0.2
  Downloading Flask-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting idna==3.3
  Downloading idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting influxdb-client==1.23.0
  Downloading influxdb_client-1.23.0-py3-none-any.whl (522 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==2.0.1
  Downloading itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==3.0.2
  Downloading Jinja2-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1.tar.gz (18 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.21.4
  Downloading numpy-1.21.4.zip (10.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting opencv-python-headless==4.5.4.58
  Downloading opencv-python-headless-4.5.4.58.tar.gz (89.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-et3mksl1/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-li1hlg53/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version<='"'"'3.9'"'"' and sys_platform == '"'"'linux'"'"' and platform_machine == '"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.21.0; python_version<='"'"'3.9'"'"' and sys_platform == '"'"'darwin'"'"' and platform_machine == '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version=='"'"'3.9'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.21.2; python_version>='"'"'3.10'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (71 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Downloading setuptools-58.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Downloading wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting scikit-build
    Downloading scikit_build-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
  Collecting cmake
    Downloading cmake-3.21.4.tar.gz (31 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
  Collecting pip
    Downloading pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
  Collecting numpy==1.21.2
    Downloading numpy-1.21.2.zip (10.3 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
  Collecting packaging
    Using cached packaging-21.2-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
  Collecting distro
    Using cached distro-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Collecting pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2
    Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: numpy, cmake
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): started
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
    Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for numpy: filename=numpy-1.21.2-cp310-cp310-linux_armv7l.whl size=16741198 sha256=5b4a1047de379ce3106c19b339167afcf9845366cd1f027d737b8c45f962940d
    Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/55/ca/9f/48d8bbedba076d0949e6d329c6aad3705267c63cc38521852d
    Building wheel for cmake (PEP 517): started
    Building wheel for cmake (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python /tmp/tmpwvmh9dg5_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpll8wsnma
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-fbue14m3/cmake_b604147fe6164d639ebb2ae896d8d802
    Complete output (9 lines):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r9cuk4k1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 564, in setup
        cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r9cuk4k1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 95, in __init__
        self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r9cuk4k1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 81, in get_cmake_version
        raise SKBuildError(
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  
    Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for cmake
  Successfully built numpy
  Failed to build cmake
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for cmake which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
  WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/6c/4cdac3b2eb23337321a5e7d2db55ed0a1348333db99085f96e93c7cf18d0/opencv-python-headless-4.5.4.58.tar.gz#sha256=3e32018e65eabc9aab10c7a109be5f735cf2c3934a47025b6903dcec034d460b (from https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python-headless/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-et3mksl1/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-li1hlg53/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version<='"'"'3.9'"'"' and sys_platform == '"'"'linux'"'"' and platform_machine == '"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.21.0; python_version<='"'"'3.9'"'"' and sys_platform == '"'"'darwin'"'"' and platform_machine == '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version=='"'"'3.9'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.21.2; python_version>='"'"'3.10'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python-headless==4.5.4.58 (from versions: 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python-headless==4.5.4.58
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r req.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Unable to find image 'influxdb:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/influxdb
docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
Unable to find image 'ultimate_hydroponics:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ultimate_hydroponics, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

*EDIT*
error doesn't changes even if I change opencv2 version or python version
I also tried `FROM arm32v7/python:latest` no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't solved this already, your error is nothing to do with opencv - it's cmake:

> Building wheel for cmake (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'

which is required to install opencv.

You may find this thread helpful: [ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732353/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-opencv-python-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be) - there's an answer in that list that contains a Dockerfile which may work for you.